# .net MAUI Picker SelectedItem does not cause item to display when inside collection

Tags: xaml, maui, selection, picker, selecteditem

the picker is inside a collection and is rendered per row, the select ation works and triggers the command but it doesnt show the selected item when form is restored, it shows empty item instead of address proprety which is bound to selectedItem inside xaml.

here is the xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:appCtrl="clr-namespace:WS.ORD.Apps.POS.Controls"
             xmlns:appVM="clr-namespace:WS.ORD.Apps.POS.ViewModels"
             xmlns:appModel="clr-namespace:WS.ORD.Apps.POS.Models"
             x:Class="WS.ORD.Apps.POS.Views.PrinterSettingsPage"
             x:Name="page">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <appVM:PrinterSettingsVM />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" />
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}" Spacing="30" Margin="100,50">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="appModel:PrinterModel">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type appVM:PrinterSettingsVM}},Path=Devices}"
                         ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"
                         HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <Picker.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=BindingContext.PrinterSelectCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Picker.Behaviors>
                        </Picker>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

here is codebehind:

```
  public partial class PrinterSettingsPage : ContentPage
  {
      public PrinterSettingsPage()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
  }
```

here is the viewmodel:

```
namespace WS.ORD.Apps.POS.ViewModels
{
    internal class PrinterSettingsVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ICommand PrinterSelectCommand { get; private set; }


        public PrinterSettingsVM()
        {
            this.Devices[0] = "device1";
            this.Devices[1] = "device2";
            this.Devices[2] = "device3";


            this.Printers = new List<PrinterModel>()
            {
                new PrinterModel { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Printer 2", Address="device1" },
                new PrinterModel { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Printer 2", Address="device2" }
            };
        }


        private string[] _devices = new string[3];
        public string[] Devices
        {
            get { return this._devices; }
            set
            {
                this._devices = value;

                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Devices)));
                }
            }
        }


        private IEnumerable<PrinterModel> _printers;
        public IEnumerable<PrinterModel> Printers
        {
            get { return this._printers; }
            set
            {
                this._printers = value;

                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Printers)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

finally the model:

```
namespace WS.ORD.Apps.POS.Models
{
    public class PrinterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        private string _address;
        public string Address
        {
            get { return this._address; }
            set
            {
                this._address = value;

                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Address)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does “when form is restored” mean?

Comment: actually i simplified the scenario, all data was loaded from db, but anyway what expected is pickers in the page show the selected items when form renders it means 'device1' and 'device' be the selectedItems of two pickers but they are empty

Comment: `when form is restored` Can you elaborate on the specific scenario of your data recovery?

Comment: oh, forget about the form restore, in very simple scenario when this app starts the expected behavior is to see the pickers selected, but it doesn't, i think it is bug in .net maui framework

Answer (score 0):

> i cant figure out the why binding here dont work

You can try to add a variable `SelectedAddress` to save the selected item and initialize it in the constructor of your viewmodel.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class PrinterSettingsVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       // add SelectedAddress to save the selected item
       private string _selectedAddress;
       public string SelectedAddress
       {
           get { return this._selectedAddress; }
           set
           {
               this._selectedAddress = value;

               if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
               {
                   this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.SelectedAddress)));
               }
           }
       }


       public PrinterSettingsVM()
       {
           this.Devices[0] = "device1";
           this.Devices[1] = "device2";
           this.Devices[2] = "device3";

           //initlize variable SelectedAddress
           SelectedAddress = Devices[1];


          //For the sake of brevity, omit other codes
       }



     //For the sake of brevity, omit other codes


   }
```

Usage example:

```
           <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type appVM:PrinterSettingsVM}},Path=Devices}"
                     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type appVM:PrinterSettingsVM}},Path=SelectedAddress}"
                     Margin="0,0,0,10">
```

**Update:**

> but since my pickers are per row generated inside a
> BindableLayout.ItemTemplate it is impossible to use a single property
> for all pickers, also list items are dynamically added so i have no
> idea how many selectedAddress will be necessary.

You can put the `Devices` and `SelectedAddress` inside of `PrinterModel`.

1.you can add property `Devices` and `SelectedAddress` into model `PrinterModel.cs`

```
public class PrinterModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //add the Devices inside of PrinterModel
    public List<string> Devices { get; set; }


    //add a property SelectedAddress
    private string _selectedAddress;
    public string SelectedAddress
    {
        get { return this._selectedAddress; }
        set
        {
            this._selectedAddress = value;

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.SelectedAddress)));
            }
        }
    }



    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return this._address; }
        set
        {
            this._address = value;

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Address)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.And initialize property `Devices` and `SelectedAddress` in the constructor of `PrinterSettingsVM.cs`,just as follows:

```
public class PrinterSettingsVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand PrinterSelectCommand { get; private set; }

    List<string> devices;


    public PrinterSettingsVM()
    {
        devices = new List<string>();
        devices.Add("device1");
        devices.Add("device2");
        devices.Add("device3");


        this.Printers = new List<PrinterModel>()
        {
            //new PrinterModel { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Printer 2", Address="device1" },
            //new PrinterModel { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Printer 2", Address="device2" }

            //set the SelectedAddress
            new PrinterModel { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Printer 2", Address="device1" ,Devices=devices,SelectedAddress=devices[0] },
            new PrinterModel { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Printer 2", Address="device2",Devices=devices, SelectedAddress=devices[2]}
        };


        PrinterSelectCommand = new Command(DoSomething);
    }

    private void DoSomething(object obj)
    {

    }

    private IEnumerable<PrinterModel> _printers;
    public IEnumerable<PrinterModel> Printers
    {
        get { return this._printers; }
        set
        {
            this._printers = value;

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Printers)));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

3.modify the data bind as follows:

```
    <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}" Spacing="30" Margin="100,50" Grid.Row="1">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="appModel:PrinterModel">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"  BackgroundColor="Pink"/>

                    <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
                     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress}"
                     Margin="0,0,0,10">

                    </Picker>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: my problem is not the storage, actually this page loads data from sqlite, i simplified it for this post to work with in memory data. my main problem is the pickers behavior, they are expected to be selected when page shows up at app startup because their bound property is  a bindable property named 'PrinterModel.Address' and are seeded with 'device1' & 'device2' at collection initialization.but picker finally shows up as unselected. i cant figure out the why binding here dont work

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: thank you for answering, but since my pickers are per row generated inside a BindableLayout.ItemTemplate it is impossible to use a single property for all pickers, also list itms are  dynamically added so i have no idea how many selectedAddress will be necessary. your approach works when a picker is declared inside page xaml and is bounded to a bindable property, but my case is defferent

Comment: Hi @BehnamAbdy, please check my updated answer at the bottom of my reply.

Comment: finally i solved the problem, i put this comment here to help other guys struggling with the same issue, i put the datetemplate inside a listview instead of verticalstacklayout or collectionview and it started to work, ridiculous. but this approach also has oneother mysterious issue , when closing the form selectionchange associated command of every picker gets called with a null argument,

Comment: hi, i tried your solution but some weird xaml exceptions showed up.anyway thank u a lot

Comment: The problem you mentioned did not arise on my side.  Could you please share [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here?